# Run telegraf as daemonset

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, telegraf, daemonset

I would like to run telegraf as daemonset but it complains about volumemounts.

I've followed [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-kubernetes-docker-cluster/) article to create my kubernetes cluster.

Now try to follow [this](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-architecture/) article to setup telegraf metrics sendings to our kafka endpoint.

[This](https://pastebin.com/jzq6aUpE) is my yaml configuration.

When I try to run kubectl apply -f /tmp/telegraf.yaml
I got this error:

```
configmap/telegraf unchanged
The DaemonSet "telegraf" is invalid:
* spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[1].name: Not found: "docker"
* spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[3].mountPath: Invalid value: "/var/run/docker.sock": must be unique
```

What is the issue to move forward?

Answer (score 2):

Remove these lines from manifest:

```
- name: docker
  mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the official telegraf-ds chart: https://github.com/influxdata/tick-charts/tree/master/telegraf-ds. They maintain it, so no need to re-implement yourself. Just override the config to send to kafka.

Note that they never merged it to stable so `helm install stable/telegraf-ds` won't work. Just clone the repo and install from source, or package yourself and put somewhere.

Comment: I'll try this one too.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here's my configuration yaml for running Telegraf as a daemonset. Contains both a ConfigMap and the Daemonset which references the ConfigMap. Intentionally left the output of the HTTP output blank.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: telegraf-config
data:
  telegraf.conf: |+
    [global_tags]
      datacenter = "aws"
    [agent]
      interval = "10s"
      round_interval = true
      metric_batch_size = 1000
      metric_buffer_limit = 10000
      collection_jitter = "0s"
      flush_interval = "10s"
      flush_jitter = "0s"
      precision = ""
      omit_hostname = false
    [[outputs.http]]
      <intentionally left bank>
    [[inputs.cpu]]
      percpu = true
      totalcpu = false
      collect_cpu_time = false
      report_active = false
    [[inputs.disk]]
      ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs","tracefs"]
    [[inputs.diskio]]
    [[inputs.net]]
    [[inputs.kernel]]
    [[inputs.mem]]
    [[inputs.processes]]
    [[inputs.system]]
    [[inputs.system]]
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: telegraf
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: telegraf
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: telegraf
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: telegraf:1.10.0
          name: telegraf
          volumeMounts:
            - name: telegraf-config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
              subPath: telegraf.conf
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: telegraf-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: telegraf-config
```